# How to wait for a thread to do something before continuing on another thread in Java?

Tags: java, wait, synchronized, notify

I have a graphical user interface named Welcome, created with JFormDesigner. I want to wait until a button is clicked on that form before continuing my application.

I am doing this using `synchronized` and instancing the GUI as the object to wait for.

```
synchronized(new Welcome()) {
    wait();
}
```

Inside of my GUI, I have a start button which when clicked runs this:

```
public void startScript() {
    synchronized(this) {
        notify();
    }

    // Close the GUI
    dispose();
}
```

The GUI successfully loads however, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
>       at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
>       at dtohh.main.Main.(Main.java:20)
>       at dtohh.tests.Tests.main(Tests.java:11)

before I can even press the Start button on my GUI. When I then press the button, the script ends and does nothing more.

I added this to test if it was working correctly:

```
synchronized(new Welcome()) {
    wait();
}

System.out.println("Test");
```

But after the button is pressed, the application exits and the output is not shown. How can I wait for the button to be pressed correctly?

Comment: the first snipet will not work as you will call `wait` on `this` and not on `new Welcome()` object - this is why you see this exception. This is quite pointless to create new instance there as you will not be able to call notify nor wait on this object on which you are syncronizing.

Comment: What should I be waiting on? and how do I notify the previous thread that the process is done? @michalk

Comment: You will have to share an object between those threads which you will be waiting and notifying on. And also you should have some condition that you will be waiting on - just check the [`docs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--)

Comment: So I need to create a new class, ie, `SyncThread`, create a static instance both threads can use and then use that as the object? @michalk

Comment: And also I think you do not have to use low level wait/notify for this - check [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

Comment: I basically just want to start my GUI (`new Welcome()` starts it), when I press a button (`startScript()` is the eventListener), it continues the script. `CountDownLatch` did not work for me @michalk

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out, I need to wait on the `Welcome.class` instance and notify using `this` on the second thread.

Main thread:

```
Welcome gui = new Welcome();
syncronized(gui) { gui.wait(); }
```

Second thread:

```
private void onStart() {
    syncronized(this) { notifyAll(); }
    dispose();
}
```